# Using files from the same module in Rust

Tags: rust

I have this file structure:

```
src
├── core
│   ├── game.rs
│   ├── math.rs
│   └── screen.rs
├── core.rs
└── main.rs
```

Inside of `core/screen.rs` I have a struct `Screen`. I can use this struct and its function in `main.rs` like

```rust
mod core;

fn main() {
  let s = core::screen::Screen::new();
}
```

That works, however the problem is, inside of `core/game.rs` I can't use that same struct.
I've tried `use` and `mod` but I can't figure it out.
Inside core/game.rs

```rust
pub struct Game {
  screen: ?????? // Should be core::screen::Screen?
}
```

And for those wondering, the contents of core.rs looks like

```
pub mod math;
pub mod screen;
pub mod game;
```

Right now the core.rs file doesn't exactly have a use except for a very weird namespace almost but it will have functions in the future.

Comment: Aside: I'd avoid using `core` as a module name, to avoid conflict/ambiguity with [The Rust Core Library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepend it with `crate::`:

```
// core/game.rs

pub struct Game {
  screen: crate::core::screen::Screen
}
```

Or throw a `use crate::core::screen;` at the top of the file and then use `screen: screen::Screen`.

Comment: `super::screen::Screen` would also work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the crate keyword but I was using that in a way such as `use crate::core::screen` which doesn't work. Using crate worked for me.